# How well do Python sets randomize?

Tags: python, random, hash, set

First of all, I know that I should never attempt what I describe in this question and this is purely hypothetical so please don't yell at me.

Python sets don't maintain order because they are hash-maps without the map part. So I was wondering how well they are at randomizing things. It obviously isn't enough for crypto, and won't work on ints (because Python hash is identity on ints), but is it good enough for games and stuff?

It makes sense that it would work decently because its modding on a hash, but I'm not really sure how good that hash is and how well it'll work for randomizing.

P.S: Sets will always return the same shuffle for the same values, but  you can assume that that isn't a problem.

Comment: What do you mean by "randomize"?  What do you mean by "good enough for games and stuff"?  You can use set iteration order if *you don't care* about the order.  If you care about the order in any way --- wanting it to be a particular way, or not be a particular way, or be predictable, or be unpredictable --- you shouldn't rely on the iteration order.

Comment: this is definitely definitely not a dupe of that question

Comment: @undergroundmonorail agreed

Comment: @BrenBarn I was asking how good it was if I wanted it unpredictable.

Comment: @Maltysen it's horrible. It's very predictable, in fact that's the reason it exists.

Comment: Python's hashing is designed to minimize hash collisions of string keys, so it might be ok for your needs. But really, it'd be much better to use shuffle or sample.

Answer (score 2):

a `set` doesn't have an order, so by definition it can't randomize order. Iteration order isn't usable if you care about order. As BrenBam says, if you care about the order *in any way*, you can't rely on it because it's an implementation detail.

The correct way to randomize order is `random.shuffle`

```
some_set_of_stuff = set(...)
some_list_of_stuff = list(some_set_of_stuff)  # you MUST make an ordered container for this!
random.shuffle(some_list_of_stuff)
```

Or you could use `random.sample` if you really need to.

```
some_set_of_stuff = set(...)
randomized = random.sample(some_set_of_stuff, len(some_set_of_stuff))
```

Comment: I am using `random.shuffle(list())` in my actual project. I was just curious about exactly how bad it would be not to.

Comment: @Maltysen well that depends on whether you want it to be shuffled or not.........

Comment: I do want it randomzied.

Comment: Then you have to randomize it. `set(...)` is not randomized, it's just not in any order that matters to a human.